# Why won't SSR work in my new Laravel 10 application?

Tags: laravel, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I am struggling to get Inertia SSR working in my application. I tested in a brand new Laravel application and I'm getting the same result, content doesn't seem to be rendering on the server side.

1. I created a new Laravel application.
2. I have followed all of the [steps](https://inertiajs.com/server-side-rendering) for implementing SSR.
3. I ran npm run build
4. I started ran php artisan inertia:start-ssr
5. I refreshed my application and looked at the source code. I do not see any server rendered code.

**resources/js/ssr.js**

```
import { createSSRApp, h } from 'vue';
import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-renderer';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import createServer from '@inertiajs/vue3/server';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';

createServer((page) =>
    createInertiaApp({
        page,
        render: renderToString,
        title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
        resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
        setup({ App, props, plugin }) {
            return createSSRApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
                .use(plugin)
                .use(ZiggyVue, {
                    ...page.props.ziggy,
                    location: new URL(page.props.ziggy.location),
                });
        },
    })
);
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build && vite build --ssr"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.0",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
        "@vue/server-renderer": "^3.4.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
        "axios": "^1.6.4",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.31",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
        "vite": "^5.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.4.0"
    }
}
```

I know this question has been answered before. I have not been able to find any solutions in any of those threads. Has anyone run into this before? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have node installed on your server?

Comment: Yes, node is installed. the ssr server starts up fine. No errors on the node side either.